# EChart XAxis Line not rendered?

Tags: javascript, angular, echarts, ngx-echarts

Trying to draw the XAxis Line in this [EChart Stackblitz Demo using Angular and Ngx-Echarts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kvcs1k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts).

This is the line configuration.  It works on the Y Axis, however on the X axis the line is not being rendered.  Any ideas?

```
          axisLine: {
            lineStyle: {
              color: 'blue',
              width: '4',
            },
          },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the [`show` option](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.axisLine.show) in the configuration. The docs say it should default to `true`, but that doesn't appear to be the case in your StackBlitz.

```
axisLine: {
  show: true,
  lineStyle: {
    color: 'blue',
    width: '4',
  },
},
```

[Here's a forked StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gvn78x?file=src/app/hello.component.ts).

Comment: Ah ... Good catch ... Yes it defaults to true on the Y Axis ...